# How to read bmp in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to read bmp by using jupyter and here is the code I used:

```
from PIL import Image
img= Image.open('/Users/hln/Downloads/Lab/Data/G/0-96um_2-50cP_PVP_40x_Set-1.bmp')
frame_1_bw = img.convert(mode="L")
plt.imshow(frame_1_bw,cmap='gray',vmin=0,vmax=255)
```

However, I cannot run these codes and the error shows that:

No such file or directory: '/Users/hln/Downloads/Lab/Data/G/0-96um_2-50cP_PVP_40x_Set-1.bmp'

I copy the path from the info of the bmp but I have no idea why it doesn't work. Does it matter that the laptop I use is Mac, but the code used to load the bmp is for Windows?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is frame_1_bw? What is plt? I can guess it is matplotlib pyplot as plt but I don't have to guess, it's up to you to provide all the information and a minimum executable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the file path hardcoded, the path does matter on different device. Try putting the code and the file in the same folder/directory and you just need to call the filename on your python file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code gave me no errors. Check that the file exists at that path, the error must be there. If you have copied the code from another computer then you must change the path to the file. It doesn't matter the difference between windows or mac, it matters that that path exists and actually points to the file you are looking for.  Furthermore, you may need `plt.show()` after `plt.imshow(frame_1_bw,cmap='gray',vmin=0,vmax=255)` to actually show the image.
[Matplotlib bug #12018](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12018/)